# дОбуток чи добУток

Tags: наголос

Усі словники дають добУток. Усі учні з усіх регіонів України кажуть дОбуток. Як краще?

P. S. Многочлен/багаточлен та точка/крапка - я навіть не торкаюся.

Comment: Я гадаю, що вам потрібно трішки доповнити відповідь і знайти ще якісь приклади, де був би "дОбуток". Наприклад, коли я вчився в школі, то ніколи такого варіанту не чув.

Comment: Погоджуюсь. Питання треба доробити зі вказанням додаткових джерел. Інакше доведеться закривати.

Comment: Чесно кажучи, я не зрозумів, як другий параграф стосується запитання. Це мало бути інше запитання?

Answer (score 3):

**ДОБУ́ТОК**

[Правопис 2019](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf): визначає, що у словах із постійним наголосом невиразний звук перевіряємо за словником:

[**СЛОВНИК НАГОЛОСІВ**](https://mila.co.ua/2017/12/03/slovnyk-nagolosiv/)

Answer (score 1):

Ну, мені здається, що "Усі учні з усіх регіонів України кажуть дОбуток" — це такий-сякий аргумент. Адже опиратися потрібно на офіційні джерела, і ви праві — [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/dobutok) і [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=22982&page=780) пишуть, що потрібно казати добУток. Також такий варіант я зустрів в [Словнику наголосів](http://mila.co.ua/2017/12/03/slovnyk-nagolosiv/) (однак, не впевнений, що це офіційне джерело).

П.с. хоч це і не стосується питання, але:

Різниця між крапкою і точкою — [тут](http://%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE.%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80/11/12/455-urok-229-tochka-chi-krapka.html).

В [блозі](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2013/12/131225_ponomariv_blog4_ko) О. Пономарева пише, що "многочлен" — суржик і його варто замінити на "багаточлен". Хоч я зрозумів, що зараз вживаються [обидва варіанти](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD).

Comment: [e2u](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=product&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) з вами не згоден.

Comment: Так, лише мій викладач математичного аналізу в ПолтНТУ Недобачій С. І. казав "багаточлен". А в КНУ всі вимовляли "многочлен".

Comment: @Yola, дякую за надання хорошого контраргументу. Але я бачу, що словник на який ви посилаєтеся (а саме Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики 2010р. (Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко) ) був укладений двома вченими-математиками, чи не могли вони допустити помилку?

Comment: Хоч ще бачу, що інший словник (Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки). Частина І англійсько-українська 2010р. (О. Кочерга, Є. Мейнарович) ) теж дає варіант "дОбуток", а це вже дивно, так як Кочерга - доктор філологічних наук.

Comment: Цікаво. Все життя (ще зі школи) був певен, що в математичному сенсі правильно _до́буток_. (Звісно, що я помилявся, але якщо кількість тих, хто так помиляється, справді велика, то це колись може й стати новою нормою.)

Comment: _Багаточлен/многочлен_ — на щастя, словники наразі фіксують і так, і так (СУМ-20: [багаточлен](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=192564&page=95), [многочлен](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=51889&page=1650); словник наукової мови Кочерги й Мейнаровича: [багаточлен](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=багаточлен&dicts=5), [многочлен](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=многочлен&dicts=5)). Тож формально можна і так, і так. Хоча професійні математики наразі все ж частіше чомусь схиляються до _многочлена_.